# Comments whitelisting in Instagram

Tags: comments, instagram

We are developing smartphone application which allows user to post comments on photos within Instagram

In this regard we have registered for "Comments Whitelisting" through following URL more than week back but we are yet to receive any response on the same. Since there was no response we registered again yesterday.

Below are the required details

Application Name - DietsRBS

Application client id - "e6834f8010664749a084861961c5b55d"

Contact Email Address - shilpa.parab@dmorph.com

Application Registered using Email Account - dmorph.pp2@gmail.com

Comment: What is your question?  If it is about not getting a response from Instagram, then we can't help you there.

Comment: We were under the impression that Instagram employees keep an eye on the chats here. So we are hoping that someone will notice our dilemma. I can't find any other way to contact Instagram.

Comment: If you need to go to a 3rd party site, then they have very poor service indeed.